# Changing number of rows based on changing vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame listed as follows:

```
unique Treatment Rep Beak time  nx  survival
1.1.1          1   1    1    0  25         0
1.1.1          1   1    1    0  25         0
1.1.1          1   1    1    0  25         0
1.1.1          1   1    1    2  24         0
1.1.1          1   1    1    2  24         0
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    0  25         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    0  25         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
```

I need to filter out the rows where survival is 0, but still make sure that the `time` for those individuals is represented. In essence, I would like to modify the rows such that if the values in `nx` are `>` the minimum `nx` value grouped by `unique`, the number of rows should equal the maximum `nx` value of that group subtracted by `nx`. This is the code I came up with:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(unique) %>%
mutate(nx = case_when(
nx > min(nx) ~ rep(.$nx, each = max(.$nx)-.$nx)))
```

The desired data frame should look like:

```
unique Treatment Rep Beak time  nx  survival
1.1.1          1   1    1    2  24         0 #one row left with nx of 24
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.1          1   1    1    4  17         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0 #3 rows left with nx of 22
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    2  22         0
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
1.1.2          1   1    2    4  16         1
```

I seem to be having trouble with replicating the rows the appropriate number of times. I tried to coerce it to a matrix and set `nrow = max(.$nx)-.$nx` but it didn't work out. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: are you saying that the code is showing errors? If you are using `each` in `rep`, it should be a single value

Comment: It is not clear whether you are taking the `max` of the whole column or by group. In the example, both works as 25 is common in both 'unique' group

Comment: The idea was to take the `max` by group. Most of the groups will end up having an `nx` of 25, but some are different

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
dat <- data_frame(unique = c(rep("1.1.1", 9),
                             rep("1.1.2", 10)),
                  treatment = rep(1, 19),
                  Rep = rep(1, 19),
                  Break = c(rep(1, 9),
                            rep(2, 10)),
                  time = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
                           4, 4, 4, 4, 
                           0, 0, 
                           2, 2, 2, 2, 
                           4, 4, 4, 4),
                  nx = c(25, 25, 25,
                         24, 24, 
                         17, 17, 17, 17,
                         25, 25, 
                         22, 22, 22, 22,
                         16, 16, 16, 16),
                  survival = c(rep(0, 5),
                               rep(1, 4),
                               rep(0, 6),
                               rep(1, 4))
                  )
```

First, group by `unique` and create a variable called `keep` to find the difference between `max(nx)` and `nx` within group. Then, group by `unique` *and* `survival`. Keep every instance were `survival == 1` and every instance where `survival == 0` and `nx` is equal to the minimum. After this, we need to filter out each instance of `survival == 0` that is greater than `keep` for that {unique, survival} group. We can use `row_numbers` to accomplish this, making sure we still keep each instance of `survival == 0`.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(unique) %>%
  mutate(keep = max(nx) - nx) %>% 
  group_by(unique, survival) %>%
  filter(survival == 0 & nx == min(nx) |
           survival == 1) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:unique(keep) |
           survival == 1) %>% 
  select(-keep) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 7
   unique treatment   Rep Break  time    nx survival
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 1.1.1         1.    1.    1.    2.   24.       0.
 2 1.1.1         1.    1.    1.    4.   17.       1.
 3 1.1.1         1.    1.    1.    4.   17.       1.
 4 1.1.1         1.    1.    1.    4.   17.       1.
 5 1.1.1         1.    1.    1.    4.   17.       1.
 6 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    2.   22.       0.
 7 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    2.   22.       0.
 8 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    2.   22.       0.
 9 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    4.   16.       1.
10 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    4.   16.       1.
11 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    4.   16.       1.
12 1.1.2         1.    1.    2.    4.   16.       1.
```

Comment: This does work, thank you very much! In order to handle when there is more than one instance of `survival == 0` that is greater than `keep`, I grouped it by `keep` and `unique` for the `filter`ing step and it seemed to work well. In my example there was only one situation between the `max nx` and `min nx`, but I have some more than that in other situations.